# Derive information for sub-scoring from one scoring model

Tags: machine-learning, ai-design, feature-extraction, random-forests

I am currently working in Python with a random forest algorithm to perform a scoring. My output is binary.

The idea now is to derive sub-scores from the above model that give an opinion on different topics within my dataset.

Unfortunately, I don't have an output variable for these sub-scores in my dataset, so I have the idea of deriving the information from the feature importance of the larger model.
Any ideas on how to do this methodically?

As an example:

The goal is to determine if a person is creditworthy. The dataset contains a lot of information about the person's occupation, the area where he/she lives, past payment history etc. Now I want a score for overall creditworthiness and sub-scores for

- Job features
- Features on the housing situation
- Features on the payment history/behaviour